# Как реализовать отправку сообщения с сервера на почту / телеграм (куда угодно) на php или javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, telegram-bot, вёрстка-email

На сайте сделал кнопку, при нажатии на которую собирается некоторое сообщение и отправляется на почту с помощью `mail` на php. Как я уже понял, этот метод устаревший и не надежный, так как зачастую сервер не считает нужным отправлять это письмо на почту. Поэтому возник вопрос, **как корректно сделать отправку сообщения на почту либо на телеграм / ВК с помощью ботов**? На каком языке это лучше сделать: **php** или **JavaScript**? Какие подводные камни? Буду благодарен за полезные ссылки и теорию!

Comment: Все рабочее, и все нормально mail шлет, глюки и количества это вопрос хостера, или лично настроенного сервера. Это одна история, все стольные рассылки , это совсем не связанная история с первой.И вообще учись толковым вещам, а не пытайся превратиться в спамера, с надеждой что после этого ты обретешь счастье.

Comment: никаких подводных камней, вроде бы, нет. Если вк апи, то выбор между лонгпул и коллбек зависит от Ваших требований. Язык, наверное, какой душе угодно, но я бы сделал на php